# How can I set a default input value in a repeater with Directus 9?

Tags: directus

If you have a input field one can set a default value.

If we add an input field in a repeater, we cannot set a default value.
Is it possible to set it somehow?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value of the whole object on Schema tab of the repeater field. You can try to put there value only on one of the subfields, for ex. `{ subfield_key: "value" }`

[image: Directus panel screenshot]